# WebException after 90 seconds

Tags: c#, soap, windows-mobile

I have a Windows Mobile application where users collect data then upload it to a server. The application works fine when the transaction takes less than 90 seconds but when it takes more than that I get a `WebException`.

The problem is, I cannot figure out who is throwing the exception. I can step through on the server side and it is working just fine. Since I've sent smaller amounts of data without any issues I assume it's a timeout issue but I have increased that and even set it to never timeout and it still gets the exception after 90 seconds.

The exception message, which contains only "WebException", is no help and the `InnerException` is null. The `WebException` contains a `System.Net.HttpWebResponse` with a status description of "Bad Gateway".

If you have any questions or any ideas please write them here. I'm running out of ideas of things to check.

Code:

```
private string SendDocument(XmlDocument document)
{
    byte[] fileStreamArray = ConvertXmlToByteArray(document);
    var service = new ImportExportService_TextBinding();
    service.Url = ApplicationManager.Application.Configuration.ImportServiceUrl;
    service.Timeout = int.MaxValue;
    var result = service.ImportRecoveriesCore(fileStreamArray);

    return result;
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.doInvoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters, 

WebClientAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no firewall that cuts you off? I had such problems long ago.

Comment: I have tried it with the firewall off and I get the same results. Thanks for the idea though, I'm desperate!

Comment: I was thinking more of a firewall on the network (most probably internetwork) on your domain, router or whatever that might cut it off. For instance, if the server you are using is on some company network, maybe their policy is to timeout all requests longer than 90 seconds. Also, how do you connect your mobile device, is it through Mobile network or Wireless?

Comment: Both the server and client are on my local machine. I disabled the firewall on my machine. The client is a Windows Mobile 6 Professional Emulator. I was not able to find any firewall settings on the device.

Comment: Are you using proxy on your machine in internet explorer?

Comment: And have you changed timeout on the server side?

Comment: No, I don't use a proxy. Yes, the timeout on the server side is 20:00.